# How would I plot borehole traces in 3d?

Tags: r, maps, geospatial

Borehole data contains the "collar" information: that's X,Y, and Z (Z is ground elevation, and Z=0 is some datum like mean sea level), and also borehole length in Z direction.

How can I create a 3D plot of the borehole traces (curves)? I'm looking for solutions in R but also interested in python (though haven't tagged it as such in case it just confuses).

The result might be similar to this image from ArcScene:

[image: ArcScene viewer example from rockware.com].

Here, the borehole traces are coloured by another parameter from one or more separate files, and keyed to the borehole name or some index. (This viewer also allows rotation of the viewport with mouse.)

Boreholes might also be non-vertical, and not straight.

Here are some data:

```
> dput(collars)
structure(list(boreid = c(47063L, 47311L, 49511L, 52752L, 58935L, 
58937L, 65763L, 67441L, 67442L, 77351L, 77436L, 77945L, 84156L, 
89809L, 90138L, 95482L, 96560L, 103583L, 104536L, 105222L, 105483L, 
105548L, 110720L, 180221L, 301001L, 302293L, 306496L, 306497L, 
325725L, 326668L, 327068L, 333303L, 333332L, 333927L, 374749L, 
374946L, 376243L, 376244L, 958884L, 958898L, 959394L, 965482L
), easting = c(554952L, 492126L, 537529L, 499972L, 490997L, 487258L, 
555368L, 496144L, 493860L, 451445L, 452195L, 525050L, 439191L, 
485774L, 519132L, 491804L, 459810L, 476288L, 499113L, 474318L, 
513550L, 501624L, 484463L, 489155L, 558105L, 532973L, 531296L, 
531852L, 532313L, 485727L, 540972L, 478073L, 517917L, 429608L, 
467779L, 469052L, 471671L, 457678L, 511513L, 402157L, 461493L, 
511070L), northing = c(5804714L, 5730703L, 5787590L, 5797164L, 
5782344L, 5786531L, 5797011L, 5775664L, 5776207L, 5773871L, 5771346L, 
5793440L, 5771468L, 5776930L, 5781414L, 5794889L, 5773111L, 5782370L, 
5734834L, 5732385L, 5758450L, 5781360L, 5745034L, 5769765L, 5800168L, 
5778723L, 5766709L, 5772101L, 5808899L, 5723574L, 5785123L, 5731540L, 
5761725L, 5774060L, 5774283L, 5774569L, 5779113L, 5777001L, 5773012L, 
5767950L, 5766123L, 5753167L), elevation = c(32.68, 10.4, 2, 
33.41, 16.8, 22.34, 3.64, 33.7, 12.3, 39, 45.6, 32.94, 168.2, 
13.6, 0.9, 27, 34, 21.05, 4.2, 20.7, 28.17, 20.5, 80, 160.1, 
20.7, 0.6, 8.5, 1.5, 68.6, 4.6, 5.5, 18.15, 23.5, 56.3, 27.4, 
31.6, 24.5, 36.7, 78.09, 125, 96.89, 26.75), total_depth = c(619.25, 
1773, 1238, 496.83, 900.02, 872.36, 1031.75, 1181.11, 1155, 528.8, 
775, 875.75, 249.94, 903.29, 1049.8, 178, 840.23, 727.67, 1586.47, 
353.9, 1389.2, 905, 333, 327, 1294, 3661, 2290, 1862, 1197, 1422, 
1400, 840, 1524, 221.1, 825, 849.4, 742.6, 607, 2345, 2001.8, 
1443, 2493.5)), .Names = c("boreid", "easting", "northing", "elevation", 
"total_depth"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -42L))
```

Answer (score 5):

A good option to do this is the RGL package. This allows you to draw 3d images such as these (linked from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221283/3d-scatterplot-with-colored-spheres-with-r-and-rgl)):

[image]

A good place to get some inspiration for `rgl` is to have a look at the questions about it [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r+rgl).

Another option would be the `scatterplot3d` package (image linked from [here](http://gallery.r-enthusiasts.com/graph/rainbow_in_the_RGB_space_108), link includes example code):

[image]

Carefully reading the documentation of these packages, and looking up some online examples should get you started.