# Color gradation for surface3d in R?

Tags: r

I am quite new in R language and I finally have been able to make a surface  with the fallowing code:

```
drilling_trial<- read.table("DRILLING_TRIAL.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",")
all_pit_data<- read.table("ALL_PIT_DATA.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",")
require("akima")
s <- with(all_pit_data,interp(x1,y1,z1))
library("rgl")
plot3d(drilling_trial$x,drilling_trial$y,drilling_trial$z, col = drilling_trial$d, add = FALSE, axes = TRUE, bbox = TRUE, xlab="x", ylab="y", zlab="z")
surface3d(s$x,s$y,s$z,col="gray")
```

Bynow, my surface is gray but I would like to color it with shaded off color (gradation) depending on the z position. Someone have an idea on how to do so?

Thank you,

Sim

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786189/r-4d-plot-x-y-z-colours help?

Comment: Tanks, I got some color gradation but nothing related to the z value. What I would like is to by able to separate my z (height) in say 10 sections and make it easy to change to any number of sections. Then, having a color gradation of those "horizontal slices".

Answer (score 2):

I try a couple of things and I ended up with this giving me pretty much what I wanted:

```
cols <- terrain.colors(462)
surface3d(s$x,s$y,s$z,color=cols[s$z])
```

462 being the higher of my z values! Thank you csgillespie for the link provided... I started from there!